# r - Rename R object while save()-ing it

Tags: r, save

I'm looking for a way to `save()` a variable under a different name "on the fly" in R (bear with me! I'm pretty sure that's not a duplicate...). Here is an example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
AAA = 1
BBB = 2
XXX = 3
YYY = 4
save(AAA=XXX, BBB=YYY, file="tmp.Rdat")  
# does NOT save a variable AAA to file with value 3 in it, which is the aim...
```

Basically I would like the `save()` function to take the value of `XXX` and save it to file under a variable named `AAA`. Note that this is not a question about renaming a variable: I could of course rename the variable `XXX` prior to saving, e.g. `AAA = XXX` and then `save(AAA, ..., file=...)` but this would of course mess up with the value of `AAA` in the rest of the code.

The obvious way is to create temporary variables and then restore the values:

```
AAA = 1
BBB = 2
XXX = 3
YYY = 4
AAAtmp = AAA; BBBtmp = BBB      # record values of AAA, BBB
AAA = XXX; BBB = YYY
save(AAA, BBB, file="tmp.Rdat")
AAA = AAAtmp; BBB = BBBtmp      # restore values of AAA, BBB
```

... but everyone will agree that this is quite messy (especially with many more variables).

This has been bugging me for a while, and my feeling is that the function `save()` can't do what I want. So I guess I will have to update my code and go down the path of using a different saving function (e.g. `saveRDS()`).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? It seems like saveRDS would probably be more appropriate for what you want...

Comment: @Dason: no major reason, just the way I code my stuff: I sometimes need to save a given variable under a name that already exists in the workspace (e.g. save a tmp variable and make it "look" like it's a non-tmp one). It's come up a few times in the past and each time I try to figure this out, but unsuccessfully. So this time I decided to ask the experts... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This proved to be a little trickier that I expected.  I'll be interested to see what others come up with, and also what any objections to my solution may be.

```
saveit <- function(..., file) {
  x <- list(...)
  save(list=names(x), file=file, envir=list2env(x))
}

foo <- 1
saveit(bar=foo, file="hi.Rdata")
```

Comment: Yep, that seems to work perfectly as expected. Best of all, it allows the use of `load()` at the "other end", meaning that I don't have to update all the pieces of code that actually make use of the saved data (as would be the case with `saveRDS()`/`readRDS()` for instance). I still have to define a new function `saveit()` for this solution though... IMHO it would be nice to have that inbuilt into the `save()` function itself (as per the test in my original post).

Answer (score 1):

A bit quicker than defining a function for the job, you can create a [`local`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.0/topics/local) environment:

```
local({
    AAA <- XXX
    BBB <- YYY
    save(AAA, BBB, file="tmp.Rdat")  
})
```

Because you are working and assigning to a different environment, you don't need to store temporary variables that will still be intact in the global environment:

```
> AAA
[1] 1
> BBB
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

#### A maybe helpful addition to Aarons answer:

If you want to save **and load** files with a filename you define as a string previously , consider this small modification of Aarons (very cool!) answer:

```
model_name <- "model1"

saveit <- function(..., string, file) {
        x <- list(...)
        names(x) <- string
        save(list=names(x), file=file, envir=list2env(x))
    }

fit <- somemodelingfunc(...)

saveit(fit = fit, string = model_name, file=paste(model_name, ".RData", sep=""))
```

This will adds functionality because you can pass filenames as strings without using the variables directly, which is useful if your saves-and-loads need to have a specific name that depends on context. My use case are model fits, for example where I define just the model name in the beginning of the file, but don't need to modify anything else in the script. I haven't seen a easier way to do this in R...

Comment: How could it be possible use this function to save more than one variable. For example a vector vec = seq(1,100,1) and separately and also two scalar values such as  a=0.1 and b=12, each with an individual new name?

Comment: Hello Gab! Did you try to use one of the `map` variants from the `purrr` package ?

Comment: Hello Marco, thanks for your answer, I tried to install purrr package as : devtools::install_github("tidyverse/purrr") but got the following error: > library(purrr)
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Package ‘purrr’ version 0.3.4 cannot be unloaded:
 Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘purrr’ is imported by ‘usethis’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘modelr’, ‘broom’, ‘tidyr’ so cannot be unloaded. What could I be doing wrong ? How can I install purrr package correctly ?

Comment: I would do following:

1. Be sure to have a clean working environment: Re-start RStudio.

2.  `install.packages("purrr")`

3. I suggest starting here: https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls01_map-name-position-shortcuts.html

Let me know if you have trouble make the `saveit` func work with map.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can create a list and assign all objects in the environment to each element of the list using the "get" function and then i can rename each element of the list.

Another methods might be to use the "assign" function with the "get" function

```
objectNames <- ls(all.names=T)
res <- list()
for (o in objectNames) {
    res[[paste(prefix,o,sep="_")]] <- get(o)
}
format(object.size(res), units="Gb")
```