# Variable Names in Environments

Tags: r

I wrote 2 functions to archive objects from R (with their names - that's really important for me) and, if an object is of class `lm`, to archive data used to conduct this model.

My code is below :

```
archive_object_and_data <- function(object, archiveData = TRUE, rememberName = TRUE){
    object <- deparse(substitute(object))
    md5hash <- digest(object)
    dir <- paste0(getwd(), "/")
    dir.create(file.path(dir, md5hash), showWarnings = FALSE)
    if (rememberName){
       save( file = paste0(dir, md5hash, "/obj.rda"), ascii = TRUE, list = objectName,
             envir = parent.frame(2))
    }else{
             save( file = paste0(dir, md5hash, "/obj2.rda"), ascii = TRUE, list =objectName,
             envir = parent.frame(5))}
    if ( archiveData )
       archiveDataFromObj( object, md5hash, changeBool = FALSE ) 
}
#
archiveDataFromObj <- function (object, md5hash, changeBool = TRUE)
  UseMethod("archiveDataFromObj")
archiveDataFromObj.default <- function(object, md5hash, changeBool = TRUE) {
}
archiveDataFromObj.lm <- function(object, md5hash, changeBool = TRUE) {
  extractedDF <- object$model
  md5hashDF <- archive_object_and_data(extractedDF, rememberName = changeBool)
}
```

And the object I want to archive looks like this :

```
data( iris )
test_data <- iris[,-5]
model2 <- lm(Sepal.Length~. , data=test_data)
archive_object_and_data(model2)
```

And error appears like this :

```
 Error in save(file = paste0(dir, md5hash, "/obj2.rda"), ascii = TRUE,  : 
  object ‘extractedDF’ not found 
6 stop(sprintf(ngettext(n, "object %s not found", "objects %s not found"), 
    paste(sQuote(list[!ok]), collapse = ", ")), domain = NA) 
5 save(file = paste0(dir, md5hash, "/obj2.rda"), ascii = TRUE, 
    list = objectName, envir = parent.frame(5)) 
4 archive_object_and_data(extractedDF, rememberName = changeBool) at archiveDataFromObj.R
3 archiveDataFromObj.lm(object, md5hash, changeBool = FALSE) at archiveDataFromObj.R#1
2 archiveDataFromObj(object, md5hash, changeBool = FALSE) at archive_object_and_data.R
1 archive_object_and_data(model2)
```

Can any1 help me with this problem?
It looks like there's a problem with that line :(

```
}else{
             save( file = paste0(dir, md5hash, "/obj2.rda"), ascii = TRUE, list =objectName,
             envir = parent.frame(5))}
```

Comment: Identifying bugs in your R code is generally off topic on CV. With `lm` objects, isn't the data already in `$model`? I'm not sure you need to get it separately.

Comment: It's a prob with variable names in different environments. I want to save them separetly

Comment: I'm not sure what name you are trying to associate with the lm data, but doing parent.frame like that seems fragile. If you just want to rename objects as you save them, consider a solution like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248065/r-rename-r-object-while-save-ing-it